# How to query an MS Access DB with VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

so I have an MS Access DB and I need to write a VBA code that finds and displays a certain value.

Here's what I have so far but it doesn't do anything

```
Public Function findInDb()
Dim mySQL As String
Dim custID As Integer

custID = "13"

mySQL = "SELECT Orders.CustomerID FROM Orders  " & _
       "WHERE [CustomerID] = orderDate"

DoCmd.RunSQL mySQL


End Function
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd897494%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: how are you trying to run this? Why not just put that in  SQL in a query? If you are going to put it in VBA, what are youu doing with the result  of running the SQL?

Comment: ok, so in ms access I want to write a piece of VBA code that finds and displays the required vakue.

Comment: When you run a SQL in MS Access, you can also get the result. Why do you need VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DlookUp` instead.

```
Public Function findInDb()

    Dim intCustID As Integer, custID As Integer
    custID = 13

    intCustID = DLookup("[CustomerID]", "Orders", "[CustomerID]=" & custID)

End Function
```

Also

`Docmd.RunSQL` is ONLY good for Action queries (Append, Update, Delete). It is not for Select Statements.

Answer (score 0):

DoCmd.RunSQL doesnt return any results. Thus it runs the query, but the resultant CustomerID value cannot be returned back to you.

Santosh suggests DLookup, but this is very poor from a performance viewpoint. I'd recommend using ado; To do this you'll need to add a reference to the most recent (highest numbered) library of "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects" appearing in the references list in your copy of ms access. With this reference defined use this code:

```
dim intCustID as long
dim rst as object
set rst = createObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rst.open "SELECT CustomerID FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID = " & CustID _
    , currentproject.connection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
intCustID = rst.fields(0)  'or if you prefer rst!CustomerID
set rst = nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Built-in functions are preferred than external libraries.

Another way

```
Sub test()

    Dim rsCust As DAO.Recordset
    Dim db As Database
    Set db = CurrentDb

    Dim custID As Integer, resultCust As Integer
    custID = 2

    Dim mySQL As String
    mySQL = "SELECT CustomerID FROM [Orders] WHERE CustomerID =" & custID

    Set rsCust = db.OpenRecordset(mySQL)
    resultCust = IIf(rsCust.EOF And rsCust.BOF, -1, rsCust(0))

End Sub
```